# Javascript code does not work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax

I am designing a web app for an iPhone.  When the user presses a button, it sends a JSON message to the web server with three values, and in return receives a JSON status response.
The javascript is below.

```
var args = {};
args.Val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Val1").value);
args.Val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Val2").value);
args.Val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("Val3").value);
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(args);

if(window.XMLHttpRequest)           // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera,
{
    ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject)       // code for IE6, IE5
{
    ajaxReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

ajaxReq.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (ajaxReq.readyState==4 && ajaxReq.status==200)
    {
         rsp = JSON.parse(ajaxReq.responseText)
         if(parseInt(rsp.Status) == 0)
         {
            document.getElementById("Status").value = "OK"
         }
         else
         {
            document.getElementById("Status").value = "Fail"
         }
    }
}
ajaxReq.open("POST", "Handler.json", true);
ajaxReq.send(jsonString);
```

When I test this with a desktop browser (Firefox or Chrome), it works just fine, 
The server gets the message, and returns the status, and the status is displayed on the
screen.  If I browse with an iPhone using Safari, it does not work.  I never get a status response, and sometimes the browser "locks up" and will not send the JSON message when I
press the button.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using iOS 6 and have Safari 6 on your computer, you can plug your iPhone into your computer and get a web inspector which will show you any JavaScript  errors that are happening. http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/ You might also consider using a JavaScript framework, like JQuery that handles the intricacies of cross browser features like AJAX.

Comment: Completely agree with Cyphun. Look into AJAX with jQuery - make your life a million times easier and your code cross compatible. If it still doens't work, connect your iphone to your mac and use the web inspector to examine the console (not you need to allow developer mode in the iphone settings)